# Problems with video brightness android tablet

Tags: android, settings, tablet, brightness

I have a Vankyo S20 tablet that I watch videos on. I was using MX Player but it had problems with scenes that had dark areas (artifacting?) I did lots of research and was able to find a solution. It was to try a better player.

Ok, so I installed several video players to see which would be best for my needs and I have noticed one common problem across the board. It doesn't matter what order I try, the results are always the same: the brightness drops.

In the apps, I adjust the brightness there (usually 42%) then I swipe down the notification panel and as soon as I tap the slider, whether it be + or - , there's an immediate change. The picture becomes crisp and clear. But as soon as the notification panel is swiped up, the video instantly drops the brightness level to what it was. There is a noticeable difference.

I've tried moving the slider and just tapping the video so that the notification panel disappears and it still does this. I've switched the order by doing the slider before the player's brightness, same results. I've even disabled battery optimization to no avail.

How can I keep that temporary brightness? I've even left the notification panel as is to see if it would revert and it did not.

I am currently on Android version 9

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To my experience MXPlayer is already very close to perfect when it comes to decoding. If the hardware decoder on your device has problems you can switch to software decoding. So I would first check all the options MXPlayer provides. Alternatively I would check VLC player. BTW this site is for development questions, so unless you plan to develop your own player you are a bit OT here.